# translation in cakephp returning invalid characters

Tags: cakephp

I am working on cakephp project where i've to translate content of my site from english to arabic. I am using cakephp default translation. The translation of english to arabic working fine but there are some invalid characters coming after the translation. I am echoing following string:-

```
<?php echo __('DISCOVER_PLACES'); ?>

I want to echo the DISCOVER_PLACES in arabic. But i am getting following result:-

اكتش�? أماكن جديدة

There are some invalid characters �? How to solve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.
```

Comment: Either your po files or your application itself is not utf8

Comment: po files means which file?

Comment: po file **S** are [how translations are defined by default](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files). Please edit the question to indicate the version of cakephp you are using, and the contents of any relevant files if you still have a question.

Comment: the version is 2.4.2